# How to unbold listchars

Tags: vim, gvim

My listchars characters looks like they are in bold as shown in screenshot below. How do I unbold them?

I think it's set under the colorscheme but I don't know which setting to change.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The *listchars* characters are highlighted by the `SpecialKey` highlight group. To remove the boldness, use:

```
:highlight SpecialKey term=NONE cterm=NONE gui=NONE
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the setting to change! I set `highlight NonText gui=none` in the colorscheme file.